# What is gradle plugin (for example gradle plugin 4.1.1)?And Where is it stored on computer?

Tags: android, gradle

I am using Android Studio. And I have come across the term called gradle plugin. I know what the gradle is and I have already downloaded it on my pc. Actually I want to know where does the gradle plugin 4.1.1 go after the project build successfully. I am successfully to use gradle locally into my project but when it comes to use gradle plugin I have to connect my computer to the internet everytime I create a new project. Is there any way I can use gradle plugin locally?

Answer (score 0):

At least one time you should need to sync with your gradle plugins when you creating a new project then after you can use offline gradle option

Comment: will I have to do this in every project?

Comment: yes you have do in every project at minimum once